# Jquery slideUp and toggleClass at same time

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery that opens up an element and when selecting another element it toggle's the others closed.

```
$('.tab__mobile-button').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().find('.tab__mobile').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  return false;
});
```

Additionally, it also applies a toggleClass which transforms a graphic. What I'm trying to achieve is the toggleClass applying on slideUp.
The toggleClass works perfectly when selecting or unselecting the same element but when I select one element and then select another element only the slideUp applies.

How can I adjust the script to apply the toggleClass on all slideUp actions?

EDIT: HTML:

```
 <li class="tab__mobile-active">
<button class="tab__mobile-button">Course Content</button>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab__mobile">
        @Model.CourseContent
    </div>
</li>
<li>
<button class="tab__mobile-button">Who is this Course for?</button>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab__mobile">
        @Model.Participants
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sibling() method to Remove its sibling class open.

```
$('.tab__mobile-button').click(function () {
    console.log('xxv');
  $(this).parent().find('.tab__mobile').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  $(this).parents().siblings().find('.tab__mobile-button').removeClass('open')
  return false;
});});
```